# How to fix Bref serverless deploy not enough memory error?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, serverless, bref

I’m using an Ubuntu 16.04 local server in a vagrant box. I use `Laravel 8` as my framework. When I use `bref.sh` to deploy my code to serverless it pops below error

```
Cannot read file vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/ClientSideMonitoring/Exception/Configurat
ionException.php due to: ENOMEM: not enough memory, open ‘/web/liyanna.com/vendor/aws/a
ws-sdk-php/src/ClientSideMonitoring/Exception/ConfigurationException.php’
```

what should I do about this error?

Comment: Could you please share the output `php -i | grep "memory_limit"`?

Comment: memory_limit => -1 => -1

Comment: Btw this has nothing to do with php as the error message is coming from nodejs